# Converting a list of list to list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I need some help with the powerful python language :
i have this :

```
person = (

('JD', 'John Doe'),
('MP', 'Marie Lance '),
)
```

and i want to output it as :

```
[
 {'initials':'JD', 'name': 'John Doe'},
 {'initials’:’MP', 'name': 'Marie Lance'}
]
```

Comment: Are Marie Lance's initials `MP` or `JD MP`?

Comment: That's not a dict of dicts, that's a set of dicts (which isn't legal). A dict has to have keys and values, not just values. So… what output do you actually want? (Also, your input isn't a list of lists, it's a tuple of tuples, but that's less important.)

Comment: @abarnert: frozendicts might be a way around that. FWIW, I think OP wants a list of dicts

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Yes, but I don't think frozendicts are what the OP is after here.

Comment: you can have list of dicts

Comment: It might help if you show us the kind of code you want to use to access this collection.

Comment: @abarnert: who knows, OP might benefit from a light `Person` class and collect a set of them

Comment: Interesting observation: there are more contributor comments on this question than OP's responses to those comments

Comment: @storm_buster: After your update, your desired output is still a set of dicts, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have list of dicts:

```
>>> person
(('JD', 'John Doe'), ('MP', 'Marie Lance '))
>>> [ {'initials':x,'name':y} for x,y in person ]
[{'name': 'John Doe', 'initials': 'JD'}, {'name': 'Marie Lance ', 'initials': 'MP'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a dictionary of dictionaries like you described.  Each item in the dictionary must have a key.  Are looking for a list of dictionaries maybe?

Here is a solution that will convert the tuple to a list of dictionaries.  There is a more "pythonic" solution to this, but I'll give you the easier to understand one to begin with.

```
persons = (

('JD', 'John Doe'),
('MP', 'Marie Lance '),
)

new_persons = list()
for person in persons:
    initials, name = person
    new_persons.append({'initials': initials, 'name' : name})
```

Note: See hackaholics more pythonic solution.  I had the same thing, but he beat me to the punch as I was editing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[dict(zip(['initials','name'], p)) for p in person]
```